# Google's Volley lib with Authenticated Appengine endpoints?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, spdy, android-volley

Google recently released [Volley](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728&ei=JbmkUYaGAoO88wSr-4HQCg&usg=AFQjCNEyT1AnZrgVSp1BDzOBwgHglo9UpQ&sig2=LV5zKhjc2uKTnps46thWbg&bvm=bv.47008514,d.eWU) - a framework for handling network requests on Android.  My question is can/should this lib be used with Appengine's cloud endpoints?  The endpoints give you libraries to handle all the networking and authentication, but would Volley have better performance?  For example SPDY can by used with Volley when used with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), which would give some performance/battery gains.  Has anyone used Volley for authenticated requests with Appengine Cloud endpoints?

Anyone from Google want comment on the performance of the supplied Google-client-libs vs. Volley?

Answer (score 1):

I am using retrofit instead of Volley. okhttp is built-in. It is easy to handle endpoints. You can find it here:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Is it possible to have a bit more information on how you use Cloud endpoints and Retrofit together?

Comment: Using retrofit with Cloud endpoints is just like any web service.  Follow the docs on Retrofit site.  Of course you can just use the generated client libs by cloud endpoints.

Comment: Check this link for learning how to use retrofit : https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client